# syntax error in insert into statement in vb.net back end of access

Tags: vb.net, syntax, error-handling

i have created a mail tracker having a backend on ms-access 97-2003 format and all the code is fine except getting error on the said above please help on resolving the issue please refer to the screen shot and i'll provide the code below it

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\fsl.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Dim cnn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim now As Date = System.DateTime.Now()
Dim mydate As Date = now


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles quit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    rdate.Clear()
    sdate.Clear()
    orgi.Clear()
    esub.Clear()
    mno.Clear()
    comap.Clear()
    srno.Clear()
    actby.Clear()
    remark.Clear()
    tim.Clear()
    Label11.Visible = False
    srno.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    cnn.ConnectionString = dbprovider
    cnn.Open()
    Me.sdate.Text = now
    Me.tim.Text = now
    Dim sqlquery As String = "Insert into fsl([rdate],[sdate],[Originator],[Circ],[Subject],[Mno],[Comp],[Type],[subtype],[actby],[srno],[Status],[Agent],[remarks],[Tim])values (@rdate,@sdate,@Originator,@Circ,@Subject,@Mno,@Comp,@Type,@subtype,@actby,@srno,@Status,@Agent,@remarks,@Tim)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, cnn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rdate", Me.rdate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", Me.sdate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@originator", Me.orgi.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@circ", Me.circ.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", Me.esub.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mno", Me.mno.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comp", Me.comap.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Me.type.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtype", Me.subty.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actby", Me.actby.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srno", Me.srno.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", Me.status.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agent", Me.agent.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", Me.remark.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tim", Me.tim.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
    MsgBox("Record Added Successfully")

    rdate.Clear()
    sdate.Clear()
    orgi.Clear()
    esub.Clear()
    mno.Clear()
    comap.Clear()
    srno.Clear()
    actby.Clear()
    remark.Clear()
    tim.Clear()
End Sub
Private Sub type_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles type.LostFocus
    If type.SelectedItem = "E-Bridge" Then
        Label11.Visible = True
        srno.Visible = True
    Else
        Label11.Visible = False
        srno.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub subty_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles subty.LostFocus
    If subty.SelectedItem = "E-Bridge" Then
        Label11.Visible = True
        srno.Visible = True
    ElseIf subty.SelectedItem = "Churn" Then
        Label11.Visible = True
        srno.Visible = True
    Else
        Label11.Visible = False
        srno.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "VALUES" keyword.

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "Insert into fsl Values ([rdate],[sdate], ...
```

Take a look at this website:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp